# iterate over array if input element with same name, different index, same suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input elements with same name and suffix, but those input have a index (an array) like parameterName[index].PropertyName

something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="stocks[0].Key" value="MSFT" />
<input type="text" name="stocks[1].Key" value="AAPL" />
<input type="text" name="stocks[n].Key" value="ZZZZ" />
```

How I can iterate over those input elements?

something like

```
$("#stocks[x].Key").each
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `starts with`: **^** and `ends with`: **$** in the selector:

```
$('[name^="stocks["][name$="Key"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

This will select elements if the name attribute value `starts` with `stocks[` and `ends` with `Key`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0wbzud85/2/

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I not mentioned this... but I also have another inputs like <input type="text" name="stocks[0].Other" value="YYYYY" /> that not like to select, sorry for not mention it --> update: I will try it :) thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the input elements in a ul and li, like this:

```
<ul id="foo">
  <li id="1">
    <input type="text" name="stocks[0].Key" value="MSFT" />
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <input type="text" name="stocks[1].Key" value="AAPL" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can access the input elements as follows:

```
$('#foo li').each( function() { 
  id = this.id; 
  mytext =  $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();   
});
```

Comment: I can't change each input element, but you give a good idea, seems that also it is posible to wrap all input elements in a div and see all childs of this "root" div element...